# postgresql custom TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION with tsvector_update_trigger

Tags: postgresql, trigger, full-text-search

I would like to use a custom text search configuration with `tsvector_update_trigger` to be able to update tsv field with french dictionary and `unaccent`.

So I did that :

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION fr ( COPY = french );
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION fr ALTER MAPPING FOR hword, hword_part, word WITH unaccent, french_stem;
```

and then created trigger :

```
CREATE TRIGGER TS_tsv BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON books FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE tsvector_update_trigger(tsv, 'pg_catalog.fr', title, authors, descriptionText);
```

but unfortunately when I want to create or update a row I get an error telling me that fr does not exist.

How I can use this configuration with a trigger ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating the new configuration with

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION fr ( COPY = french );
```

it does not appear in `pg_catalog`, but in the current schema (`public` by default).

This is made apparent by the `\dF` command in psql:

```
test=# \dF
               List of text search configurations
   Schema   |    Name    |              Description              
------------+------------+---------------------------------------
 pg_catalog | danish     | configuration for danish language
 pg_catalog | dutch      | configuration for dutch language
 pg_catalog | english    | configuration for english language
 pg_catalog | finnish    | configuration for finnish language
 pg_catalog | french     | configuration for french language
 pg_catalog | german     | configuration for german language
 pg_catalog | hungarian  | configuration for hungarian language
 pg_catalog | italian    | configuration for italian language
 pg_catalog | norwegian  | configuration for norwegian language
 pg_catalog | portuguese | configuration for portuguese language
 pg_catalog | romanian   | configuration for romanian language
 pg_catalog | russian    | configuration for russian language
 pg_catalog | simple     | simple configuration
 pg_catalog | spanish    | configuration for spanish language
 pg_catalog | swedish    | configuration for swedish language
 pg_catalog | turkish    | configuration for turkish language
 public     | fr         | 
(17 rows)
```

In that case, the trigger should be created with:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TS_tsv BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON books
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE
  tsvector_update_trigger(tsv, 'public.fr', title, authors, descriptionText);
```

Comment: Great it works. It was that. Thank you very much Daniel.